# In Vb.Net,How to write a .csv file without Carriage Return?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am working on VS 2012, Vb.Net - .Net 4.0 framework.

My Vb.Net code is reading the .csv file and it is expected to rewrite the file without Carriage Return.

But now, Carriage Return Line Feed is created as a new line in the .csv file.
How to delete CR LF ??

```
  Public Sub Test()
            Try

                Dim reader As StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(File.OpenRead("D:\CSV\Test.csv"))
                Dim listA As New List(Of String)()


                If File.Exists("d:\CSV\TestOut.csv") Then
                    File.Delete("d:\CSV\TestOut.csv")
                End If

                Dim sw As New StreamWriter("d:\CSV\TestOut.csv")
                Dim s As String = String.Empty

                While reader.Peek() >= 0
                    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
                    Dim values As String() = line.Split(";"c)
                    listA.Add(values(0))
                    s = s + line + Chr(10)
                End While
                reader.Close()
                sw.WriteLine(s)
                sw.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try

        End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see what this had to do with `C#`. Removed tag.

Comment: I wish to add a sample csv file and screenshot of the issue, But i dont have enough points to upload files

Comment: The BOM of the file is read, and then it is also saved in the array. Is that intended?
Maybe a TextReader would be more appropriate?
Or is `bt` just forwarded to some other function?

Comment: I just took the piece of code to post it over here. Yes, this function returns byte array which is written back to a CSV file in the FTP - Linux Server.

Comment: Experts, Thank you again. I have to edit my original post to a simpler question. I believe this will help me to solve my issue.

Comment: I can't see the output since I don't have the file you are using. Maybe upload it through another service like wetransfer? anyway what is the value of the line variable? (Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine())

Comment: Don't use `WriteLine`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what the `listA` or the `values` variables are good for. You don't need them for the CRLF to LF task.

See:

```
Try
    If File.Exists("D:\CSV\Output.csv") Then File.Delete("D:\CSV\Output.csv")


    Using reader As New StreamReader(File.OpenRead("D:\CSV\Input.csv"))
    Using writer As New StreamWriter("D:\CSV\Output.csv")
        Dim strBldr As New Text.StringBuilder

        While reader.Peek > -1 ' Seen like this at MSDN page for Peek() function
            Dim line = reader.ReadLine
            ' If you really need the first value of each line, you can still do it here.
            strBldr.Append(line).Append(Chr(10))
        End While

        writer.Write(strBldr.ToString)
    End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

1. You should use the `Using`-Keyword for Streams. When leaving, `End Using` will close and `Dispose()` the stream object. It will always do, even if exceptions are thrown or you `return` a value; just like `Finally` statements in a `Try` block.
2. When you expand a `String`-Variable often at the end like `s = s + line + Chr(10)`, please consider using a `StringBuilder` which is optimized for this.
3. When you need the first and only the first value in the list, `line.Split({";"c}, 2)` will split the first value and leaves the big rest as one `String` and not maybe hundreds of `String` objects just for the garbage collection. Even more appropriate would be using `line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(";"))` which doesn't generate a rest at all.